# Safari issues, variable undefined (XML/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, safari

I have this piece of code, it works in all browsers, except for Safari:

```
        // Create a connection to the file.
        var Connect = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Define which file to open and
        // send the request.
        Connect.open("GET", "<?php echo $fileName;?>", false);
        Connect.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        Connect.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        Connect.send();

        // Place the response in an XML document.
        var TheDocument = Connect.responseXML;

        // Place the root node in an element.
        var questions = TheDocument.childNodes[0];

        // Retrieve each customer in turn.
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            console.log("fake var");
            var question = questions.children[0];
            console.log(question);
        }
```

Variable $filename is the php link to the XML file i'm reading. 
I have the following issue, the code runs into the For loop, i can log var "i", and "fake var". But once i define var question as questions.children[0], the code stops. I cant log the question var in safari.

Any ideas? ( Feedback also welcome, still learning javascript/xml )

Example of my XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Beantwoordt_kritiek id="1" admin="Jan Hut" categorie="Omgaan met elkaar" winswf="images/Kado (1).jpg">
  <gebruikers_vraag1>
    <vraag><![CDATA[Sleep de puzzelstukken naar het juiste vakje.]]></vraag>
    <s_vraag><![CDATA[sounds/puzzel.mp3]]></s_vraag>
    <thumb1><![CDATA[images/527puzzel1_1.jpg]]></thumb1>
    <thumb2><![CDATA[images/527puzzel1_2.jpg]]></thumb2>
    <thumb3><![CDATA[images/527puzzel1_3.jpg]]></thumb3>
    <thumb4><![CDATA[images/527puzzel1_4.jpg]]></thumb4>
    <vraagFoto><![CDATA[images/527puzzel1.jpg]]></vraagFoto>
  </gebruikers_vraag1>
</Beantwoordt_kritiek>
```

Comment: Are you just not giving us the XHR link or did you really type in `"<?php echo $fileName;?>"`? The latter's not going to execute the PHP (unless that's how you made your server somehow...maybe you can do that in PHP, I'm a Python person). Also, can you give us any errors that came up in your JavaScript console? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: I use FireBug, but i don't get any errors in Safari(also none in other browsers), for some reason it just cuts out. And, the file im working in is a .php file, because i need variable's for other data. You can use html in php by stopping php, type your html, and open php whenever you need it again by using `<?php echo 'your php stuf'; />`.

Comment: Ànd, xml file is in root. So if you want to test, you can replace the php echo $fileName for thisIsMyFile.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this script, so safari give back the same result.

```
<script>
function getChildren(element) {
  if (element.children == undefined) {
    var childNodes = element.childNodes
    var children = []
    for(var i = 1; i < childNodes.length; i += 2) {  // take every second element
      children.push(childNodes[i]);
    }
    return children;
  } else {
    return element.children
  }
}
</script>
```

and then call this in your script

```
var question = getChildren(questions)[0];
```

Comment: You are my god. Thanks! But, why does this script work, and why is mine not doing anything?

Comment: haha just random person to answer your question :) Chrome have a better support for this then Firefox. I made a polyfill for you to solve this problem. Firefox knows childnodes, but then you get more item then you want so we filter them out and return them. When the user using chrome it just takes the normal route... check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children